# Can we vote to skip replays in Lucioball?

Tags: overwatch

In Rocket League, whenever an instant replay is shown after a goal, players are given the option to vote to skip the replay.

Is there anything similar in Lucioball? Can we vote to skip replays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering posts like [this one that is oddly similar to your question](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758486907), it looks like this is not currently a feature (though it has been requested).

> While I enjoy seeing replays of a goal in LucioBall, I would really like it if something was implemented similar to how Rocket league handles replays where if all players hit a key/button to "skip" the replay it will skip.

Other such posts can be found [here](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758596793) or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/6shjru/lucioball_is_very_fun_but_the_goal_replays_become/).